# Yii2: How to get rid of decimals (cents) if the value is integer?

Tags: php, yii2, currency, formatter

I am using this function

```
Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(12321.00, 'EUR');
```

The result is 12 321,00 €. 
But I wanted it to show 12 321 € if the decimals are 00...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Another way would be:

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(12321.00, 'EUR',[\NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS=>100])
```

Output:

```
€12,321
```

-

```
\Yii::$app->formatter->asCurrency(9912321.00, 'EUR',[\NumberFormatter::MAX_SIGNIFICANT_DIGITS=>100])
```

Output:

```
€9,912,321
```

Comment: I just deleted my answer because it is wrong. yours is the correct approach. the formatted class will add the missing zeros if not configured to do otherwise.

Comment: Thank you very much, that's exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0):

To anybody looking for this recently, it's possible to set this globally for all numbers via https://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/2.0/yii-i18n-formatter#$numberFormatterOptions-detail

```
    'formatter' => [
        'numberFormatterOptions' => [
            NumberFormatter::MIN_FRACTION_DIGITS => 0,
            NumberFormatter::MAX_FRACTION_DIGITS => 2,
        ]
    ],
```